# How can I view saved passwords in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, password-management

In Firefox and Chrome I can see the passwords that I have saved using Options or Preferences.

Is there any way to do this in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [IE PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html) to see the passwords stored in Internet Explorer:

[image: Passview]

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I found this solution not too long ago. Use google chrome, go to bookmark, import all bookmark and passwords. Then go to manage passwords in google chrome, it will ask for your windows ID and password and viola you get the password to the website.

Comment: The User wanted to know how to view passwords in internet Explorer not importing them from chrome.

Comment: It is a clever work around.